# Skylake integrated graphics on Ubuntu - Help!

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I've searched everywhere for hours and can't find the solution. Using Skylake i5-6500 with Asus 7170 motherboard, Ubuntu 15.04. I have been unable to get the intel graphics working, even by editing grub in the terminal with the i915 preliminary = 1 setting (I did type it correctly on the screen). I can't find how to fix this. I am using Gallium graphics now, it is the only thing that works. I also have an Nvidia gtx 950, I presume once intel HD graphics are working I can then install the Nvidia driver using root .sh on the downloaded file. 
If anyone can help I will personally offer to write a tutorial on how to fix it for other newbies. It seems thousands of people are having the same issue.
Many, many thanks
Tom

Comment: Apparently, there isn't much support for Skylake in 15.04, which is not fixable. A known workaround is to add `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1`. Another workaround is to try [Intel graphics installer](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.0) (currently 1.2.0).

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both but neither seem to work. Shall I just abandon the system for six months? I am so frustrated I feel like throwing it away :( I have just spent nearly £800 on it. I just don't know what to do.

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu 15.10 and now the Nvidia card is recognised (not the internal HD530). But at least I can use it :)

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 15.04 you will need to add these kernel commands to your grub configuration. `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1` and also `nouveau.modeset=0`

I am unable to get Nvidia drivers working on 15.04.

On 15.10 I have yet to see Intel or Nvidia working for myself.

EDIT: On Ubuntu 15.04 I was able to get Nvidia graphics working. Leaving those kernel commands in place i installed via CLI `nivida-346 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings`, rebooted and everything worked.