# Laptop freezes after connecting external monitor

Tags: 14.04, drivers, intel-graphics, freeze, external-monitor

I am running **ubuntu 14.04 LTS**.Each time I connect to external display at home/workplace, my laptop freezes and then I have to restart the entire system. Please guide me in order to avoid this unnecessary restart. Thanks

OS Type: **Linux**
Release: **Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty)**
Make-Model Name: **HP-Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz**
Kernel: **4.5.3-040503-generic**
Graphics Card: **Intel® Skylake ULT GT2**

Comment: Laptop make and model, as well as kernel, and logs?

Comment: @PatrickNegus I have added details except logs. I do not know what kind of logs you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on Linux Kernel `4.5.3` which is no longer supported: (https://www.kernel.org/). I would recommend you move up to `4.8.10`
which came out a few days ago and has been working well for me. Plus users of `Cherry Trail` on the infamous `Bay Trail` bug list said yesterday it is fixing problems for them: (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051). You have an Intel `Skylake` which is also included in that bug report. I have an `Ivy Bridge` and also have side effects ever since my upgrade to kernel `4.4` used by **Ubuntu 16.04**

Other **Intel Skylake** posts that may interest you here in AskUbuntu are:

- [Ubuntu 16.04 Skylake overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830404/ubuntu-16-04-skylake-overheating)
- [No version of Ubuntu can be installed with any Skylake 6th generation Intel processor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691216/no-version-of-ubuntu-can-be-installed-with-any-skylake-6th-generation-intel-proc)
- [Intel Skylake Graphics fix crashes Nvidia card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850453/intel-skylake-graphics-fix-crashes-nvidia-card)
- [Ubuntu 14.10 LTS with new skylake processors .](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731645/ubuntu-14-10-lts-with-new-skylake-processors)
- [Ubuntu 16.04 Skylake 6th Generation Screen Flickering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752743/ubuntu-16-04-skylake-6th-generation-screen-flickering)
- [Skylake integrated graphics on Ubuntu - Help!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686164/skylake-integrated-graphics-on-ubuntu-help)

### Enough links already you're killing me!!!

Steps everyone can take are to ensure Intel microcode is up to date. See the answer in the first link at top of page.

Steps you can take is to upgrade kernel from `4.5.3` (unsupported) to `4.8.10` which has good reviews / improvments:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.10/linux-headers-4.8.10-040810_4.8.10-040810.201611210531_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.10/linux-headers-4.8.10-040810-generic_4.8.10-040810.201611210531_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.10/linux-image-4.8.10-040810-generic_4.8.10-040810.201611210531_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo reboot
```

I look forward to feedback and updating this answer as new information comes to light.

Thank you.

Comment: I have upgraded Kernal to 4.8.10 as you suggested, and after testing for few days, everything seems fine. Thanks a lot for your comprehensive explanation.

Comment: @RaziAhmed It was my pleasure. Good to hear everything is working.

Comment: I had the same issue, and changed my old kernal to 4.8.10 as suggested above. Now it is working with out any problem.  Thanks for the solution.

I am using lenovo E470 Thinkpad with Ubuntu 14.04 and Intel graphics card.

Comment: @RubanrajRavichandran Glad it worked for you. You should up-vote the answer by clicking the chevron beside it to let others know it works. Also Kernel `4.8.10` is no longer supported and you should try something more modern like `4.9.75` or `4.14.13`.